# Two knapsacks with smallest delta in sum of values

Tags: algorithm, knapsack-problem

This question is a rephrased problem I encountered during implementation of some system at work. I thought it's a bit similiar to knapsack problem and was curious to explore how it can be solved since I wasn't able to come up with a solution.

Problem statement: Given a set of items, each with weight and value, and two knapsacks, determine which items to include in both of these knapsacks so each knapsack has exactly a weight of K and the delta of sum of values of these two knapsacks is as small as possible. If it's not possible to satisfy weight constraint for both knapsacks algorithm should return nothing.

I think some sort of greedy algorithm might be a satisfying solution but not sure how to write it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved with a dynamic programming approach.  Here is an approach with linked lists.

```
from collections import namedtuple

ListEntry = namedtuple('ListEntry', 'id weight value prev')
Thing = namedtuple('Thing', 'weight value')

def add_entry_to_list(i, e, l):
    return ListEntry(i, l.weight + e.weight, l.value + e.value, l)

def split_entries (entries, target_weight):
    empty_list = ListEntry(None, 0, 0, None)
    dp_soln = { (0, 0): (empty_list, empty_list) }

    for i in range(len(entries)):
        dp_soln_new = {}
        e = entries[i]
        for k, v in dp_soln.items():
            (weight_l, weight_r) = k
            (l_left, l_right) = v

            this_options = {k: v}
            this_options[(weight_l + e.weight, weight_r)] = (add_entry_to_list(i, e, l_left), l_right)
            this_options[(weight_l, weight_r + e.weight)] = (l_left, add_entry_to_list(i, e, l_right))

            for o_k, o_v in this_options.items():
                if target_weight < max(o_k):
                    pass # Can't lead to (target_weight, target_weight)
                elif o_k not in dp_soln_new:
                    dp_soln_new[o_k] = o_v
                else:
                    diff = o_v[0].value - o_v[1].value
                    existing_diff = dp_soln_new[o_k][0].value - dp_soln_new[o_k][1].value
                    if existing_diff < diff:
                        dp_soln_new[o_k] = o_v
        dp_soln = dp_soln_new

    final_key = (target_weight, target_weight)
    if final_key in dp_soln:
        return dp_soln[final_key]
    else:
        return None

print(split_entries([
    Thing(1, 3),
    Thing(1, 4),
    Thing(2, 1),
    Thing(2, 5),
    ], 3))
```